# onClick definition missing in acsx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, onclick

Error Message:

> CS1061: 'ASP.controls_contentassignmentcontrol_ascx' does not contain
>   a definition for 'btnPrintCA_Click' and no extension method
>   'btnPrintCA_Click' accepting a first argument of type
>   'ASP.controls_contentassignmentcontrol_ascx' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

aspx:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnPrintCA" 
    OnClick="btnPrintCA_Click" runat="server"
    ImageUrl="~/Content/Image/print_32.gif" meta:resourcekey="imgBtnPrint" />
```

c# codebehind

```
public void btnPrintCA_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "_Page", "showPVDialog('ContentAssignmentPrint.aspx','')", true);
    }
    catch 
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: So `btnPrintCA_Click` is in the codebehind class of `controls_contentassignmentcontrol_ascx` and not in the page-class?

Comment: Do check in pagedirective the `Inherits` property has the same class name where `btnPrintCA_Click` is written.